# My Azure Speech recognition does not stop upon the recognition of a file

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I create an Azure Speech recognition app by using the demo code provided by Azure. However, after completing the speech recognition for an audio file, Azure Speech does not close and shows the following unless I use ctrl-c. I want to know why it does not stop.

`CLOSING on SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=..., result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=..., text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled)) CLOSING on SessionEventArgs(session_id=...)`

```
    def printRecognizedData(speech_result):
        json_obj = json.loads(speech_result.result.json)
        print(json_obj["DisplayText"])

    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: printRecognizedData(evt))

    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)

    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
```

Comment: Have you tried `close()` method as mentioned in this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/dfe81687569e67a95bcaaad3184ca949dd2c5264/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to stop upon the recognition of a file

```
try:
while(True):
frames = wav_fh.readframes(n_bytes // 2)
print('read {} bytes'.format(len(frames)))
if not frames:
break

stream.write(frames)
time.sleep(.1)

finally:    
#Stop recognition and clean up
speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
wav_fh.close()
stream.close()
```

References: [cognitive-services-speech-sdk/speech_sample.py at dfe81687569e67a95bcaaad3184ca949dd2c5264 · Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/dfe81687569e67a95bcaaad3184ca949dd2c5264/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py)

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, Azure Speech demo recognition code was still similar and it didn't terminate either after a successful recognition. This is due to the following callback code:

```
    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True
```

When `stop_continuous_recognition()` is invoked, the control is no longer within `stop_cb` and as such, didn't update the `done` flag. I moved this line to the end, as below:

```
    def stop_cb(evt):
        print(f'CLOSING on {evt}')
        nonlocal done
        done = True
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
```

This ensures `done` gets modified and it leads to a proper exit from the while loop. Here, is the entire transcription code for completeness:

```
def recognised_cb(evt):
    print(evt.result.text)

def from_file():
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="mykey", region="myregion")
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_input)
    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        print(f'CLOSING on {evt}')
        nonlocal done
        done = True
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognised_cb)
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)
```